# Do you have to always know the index where your saving in a Mongodb document array?

Tags: c#, mongodb

If you have a MongoDB array such as this:

```
"array": [
  {
    "item" : {
      "content": "",
      "extra_content": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "item" : {
      "content": "",
      "extra_content": ""
    }
  },
  {
  "otheritem" : {
      "content": "",
      "extra_content": ""
    }
  }
]
```

The items in the array can have a unique name such as "otheritem" and there are some that are duplicates.  I have been updating this by working on the array and finding the index of the unique item and using Update.Set("array." + index, bsondocument) to change the value.  Is there a better way of updating the items with unique name?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use the $ positional operator:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "stuff" : [{ "name" : "cookie" }, { "name" : "horseshoe" }] })
> db.test.update({ "_id" : 0, "stuff.name" : "cookie" }, { "$set" : { "stuff.$.flavor" : "peanut butter" } })
> db.test.findOne()
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "stuff" : [
        { "name" : "cookie", "flavor" : "peanut butter" },
        { "name" : "horseshoe" }
    ]
}
```